# How to compute derivative when a function includes two indices

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

In a weighted graph, the probability of selecting an edge between nodes $i$ and $j$ is

$$P^{R}_{ij} := \frac{[a_{ij}]^\alpha [b_{ij}]^\beta}{\sum\limits_{r \in R} [a_{ir}]^\alpha [b_{ir}]^\beta},$$

where $a_{\cdot\cdot}$ is the weight of the edge corresponding to its argument nodes. $b$ is a heuristic function. $R$ is a subset of the graph's nodes, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are some positive real numbers.

In a design problem, I need to maximise $P^{R}_{ij}$ with respect to edge weights. However, it includes both $a_{ij}$ and $a_{ir}$ terms. Now, I am wondering whether I have to compute the total derivative taking $a_{ij}$ and $a_{ir}$ independent variables. So, what is that total derivative?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{[a_{ij}]^\alpha [b_{ij}]^\beta}{\sum\limits_{r \in R} [a_{ir}]^\alpha [b_{ir}]^\beta}
$$
Consider the case where $|R|=3$ and $j=1.$ Then you have
$$
\frac{[a_{i1}]^\alpha [b_{i1}]^\beta}{\sum\limits_{r \in R} [a_{ir}]^\alpha [b_{ir}]^\beta} = \frac{[a_{i1}]^\alpha[b_{i1}]^\beta}{[a_{i1}]^\alpha [b_{i1}]^\beta+[a_{i2}]^\alpha [b_{i2}]^\beta+[a_{i3}]^\alpha [b_{i3}]^\beta} \tag 1
$$
You wrote:

> I am wondering whether I have to compute the total derivative taking $a_{ij}$ and $a_{ir}$ independent variables.

Since $j=1$ in this case, that would mean $a_{i1}$ and $a_{ir}.$ But what is $r$? In the first term in the denominator, $r=1,$ so $a_{ir}= a_{i1}$ in the second term $r=2$ and $a_{ir} = a_{i2},$ and in the third term $r=3$ and $a_{ir} = a_{i3}.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you have written "that would mean $a_{i1} and a_{ir}$." What does that mean? Furthermore, if I got it right, you are referring to the cases where $a_{ij}$ and $a_{ir}$ may be equal. So, they are not independent. In that case, what will the derivative be, then?

Comment: @Roboticist : You seem to have in mind a function of several variables: $a_{i1}, a_{i2}, $a_{i3}, \ldots , a_{i|R|},$ so that for example when $|R|=3,$ you have three variables: $a_{i1}, a_{i2}, $a_{i3}.$ If you mean the derivative of the expression on line $(1)$ with respect to one of those variables, then the quotient rule will do it. Suppose you want $$ 
\frac\partial{\partial a_{i1}} \, \frac{[a_{i1}]^\alpha[b_{i1}]^\beta}{[a_{i1}]^\alpha [b_{i1}]^\beta+[a_{i2}]^\alpha [b_{i2}]^\beta+[a_{i3}]^\alpha [b_{i3}]^\beta}. $$ Then an algebraic simplification will reduce the work:$\qquad$

Comment: $$ \begin{align} & \frac{[a_{i1}]^\alpha[b_{i1}]^\beta}{[a_{i1}]^\alpha [b_{i1}]^\beta+[a_{i2}]^\alpha [b_{i2}]^\beta+[a_{i3}]^\alpha [b_{i3}]^\beta} \\ {} \\ = {} & 1 -   \frac{[a_{i2}]^\alpha [b_{i2}]^\beta+[a_{i3}]^\alpha [b_{i3}]^\beta}{[a_{i1}]^\alpha [b_{i1}]^\beta+[a_{i2}]^\alpha [b_{i2}]^\beta+[a_{i3}]^\alpha [b_{i3}]^\beta} \tag 2 \end{align} $$ This may superficially not look simpler, but notice that when differentiating with respect to $a_{i1},$ the numerator of the fraction is now a constant, so you can just use the reciprocal rule rather than the quotient rule.$\qquad$

Comment: Recall that $\dfrac\partial{\partial x} \, \dfrac C{g(x)} = \dfrac{-Cg'(x)}{g(x)^2}.$ That is the reciprocal rule and you can use it to differentiate the expression on line $(2)$ in the comment above with respect to $a_{i1}. \qquad$ @Roboticist